# Maven Project with Spring Webflow: ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, maven, spring-webflow

I am trying to use Maven for the first time and I had a working project that is Spring WebFlow, MySQL and Hibernate is was working before I started with maven but I want to learn maven.. I am getting this error:

```
Maven Project with Spring Webflow: ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean
```

Here is my POM.XML please help

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>org.springsource.greenbeans.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>MemberInquiry</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>MemberInquiry</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <dependencies>

    <dependency>
            <groupId>c3p0</groupId>
            <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
            <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
            <version>1.4.5</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.1.21</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpcore</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.2.1</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <!-- <dependency> <groupId>org.jasig.cas</groupId> <artifactId>cas-server-core</artifactId> 
            <version>3.5.0</version> <exclusions> <exclusion> <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId> 
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId> </exclusion> </exclusions> </dependency> <dependency> 
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId> <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId> <version>1.6.6</version> 
            </dependency> -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.3.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.0.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>3.5.6-Final</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>3.8.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.aspectj</groupId>
            <artifactId>aspectjtools</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aspects</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.webflow</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webflow</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-web</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-config</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-ldap</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-cas</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-cas-client</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.7.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-aop</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>log4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.17</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>c3p0</groupId>
            <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.ldap</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-ldap-core</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.ldap</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-ldap-core-tiger</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- <dependency> <groupId>org.jasig.cas</groupId> <artifactId>cas-server-core</artifactId> 
            <version>3.5.0</version> </dependency> -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.jasig.cas.client</groupId>
            <artifactId>cas-client-core</artifactId>
            <version>3.1.12</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-ext</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.6</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.6</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- <dependency> <groupId>org.apache.directory.server</groupId> <artifactId>apacheds-core</artifactId> 
            <version>1.5.5</version> <scope>runtime</scope> </dependency> <dependency> 
            <groupId>org.apache.directory.server</groupId> <artifactId>apacheds-server-jndi</artifactId> 
            <version>1.5.5</version> <scope>runtime</scope> </dependency> -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tiles</groupId>
            <artifactId>tiles-jsp</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-nop</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <finalName>WebFlowTemplate</finalName>
    </build>
</project>
```

Answer (score 3):

You have to add dependency to `spring-orm`:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-orm</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.1.RELEASE</version>
    </dependency>
```